# Show progress bar when Angular loads its files?

Tags: angular, progress-bar

Want to show progress bar(with percentage) when Angular app is first loading(styles and js bundles). Can someone provide idea?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish that by modifying `index.html`
[please-wait](http://pathgather.github.io/please-wait/) and [pace.js](https://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/) are awesome libraries for this kind of task.

You can start displaying the wait screen from index.html and hide in angular's `AfterViewInit` or some other appropriate [lifecycle hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

Comment: All over the internet, people ask explicitly for loading percentage, and get recommended pace.js which does not do that. Thanks for introducing me to please-wait though ;)